# How to allow Windows 10 standard users to run certain application as administrator?

Tags: windows-10, active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2016

We have windows server 2016, all clients are windows 10. We want to allow the users to run certain applications (for example OpenVPN, Chrome Browser) as admin, but other applications only as a standard user.

How can we implement this?

Comment: I edited the question a bit for clarity. Please check the edit, and correct any mistakes.

Comment: What specific "admin" privileges does Chrome require – have you looked into granting just those privileges specifically instead of admin in general?

Comment: @user1686
 we have token USB and when we use this token, needed chrome run as administrator, to choosing certificate in pop up in chrome, If Chrome is not runed as admin, that pop up page will never be displayed

Comment: That's... a bit weird. I've never needed admin rights to use a smartcard on Windows, neither in Chrome nor in any other software. Staff here also routinely use smartcards via (several different) browser extensions without admin rights.

Comment: @user1686
 Of course, apart from Chrome, we have other reasons to want some programs to be able to run as administrator in standard users

Comment: What about Beyond Trust (https://www.beyondtrust.com) for creating granular credential extensions on a server for standard users.

Comment: Running Chrome as an administrator is just waiting for bad juju to happen.  I am not trying to be the "rules police" but browsers have vulnerabilities all of the time and if running as admin.. simply not good.

Comment: I don't want to know about possible problems or whether it is right or wrong to run the program with admin access. So if you know please help to this issues only